# Using PDFBox change PDF file to Bitmap, but meet some highlight part, so i got a poor conversion

Tags: java, android, pdfbox

Using PDFBox change PDF file to Bitmap, but meet some highlight part, so i got a poor conversion...

this is the wrong file page preview:

[image: the wrong file page preview]

and my code :

```java
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(assetManager.open("XXX.pdf"));
PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
pageImage = renderer.renderImage(0, 1, ImageType.ARGB);

// Save the render result to an image
String path = root.getAbsolutePath() + "/render.png";
File renderFile = new File(path);
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(renderFile);
pageImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

And then I got this result Image：

[image: got this result Image, a poor conversion]

can anybody help me? thanks a lot!

Here is the wrong file's link : https://github.com/yingbabywhen/yingbabywhen

Comment: Can you share the PDF in question? Looks like an issue with transparency...

Comment: Oh, I realize this is PDFBox for Android. That one is somewhat behind the desktop project. It would still be interesting to get the PDF to check that it works on the desktop project.

Comment: @mkl  i don't know how to upload a file to stackoverflow, so i put the file in my git: https://github.com/yingbabywhen/yingbabywhen

Comment: *"i don't know how to upload a file to stackoverflow, so i put the file in my git"* - stack overflow does not include a file attachment mechanism, one has to use external file sharing options like one's git repos, so that's ok.

Comment: One observation first: Your PDF is not completely valid, its cross reference section has gaps which is forbidden for single-revision PDFs. This usually does not immediately cause issues; if your PDFs eventually get digitally signed, though, and then incrementally updated, Adobe Acrobat will start complaining and claim changes invalidating the signature.

Comment: PDFBox for desktop displays it correctly.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr you are right, but i am using android-pdfbox ...(•_•)

Comment: @mkl THS, so it means that i  have no way to solve this problem by using PDFBOX？Unless I parse the PDF file structure myself？

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not really knowledgeable about the android-pdfbox version of PDFBox. What I mentioned as a side note most likely is not the cause of the issue here, merely a possible issue in a completely different use case.